# String similarity grouping with anonymous data

Tags: r, grouping

I work with anonymous data, where the destination may have been spelt incorrectly (I only observe an anonymized key for both the destination and origin, but I know the origin is correct).

```
origin<-c("Norway","Norway","Sweden","Sweden")
destination_typed<-c("Germany","Gerrmany","Spain","Spaiin")
df<-data.frame(origin=origin,destination=destination_typed)
df
```

I also have data on string similarity of the destinations. Again, I observe only anonymous keys for countries, and the score (how similar they are). So I do not know what is the correct spelling, i.e. I am just as happy with *Spaiin* as *Spain*, as long as they are grouped (dest_key_for_spain).

```
library(dplyr)
df_names<-expand.grid(destination_typed=destination_typed,
            destination_alternatives=destination_typed,
            stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
  arrange(destination_typed) %>% 
  mutate(similarity_score=stringdist::stringsim(destination_typed,
                                                destination_alternatives))
df_names
```

What I want is the anonymized destinations to be grouped together (e.g. if the similarity score is >0.5), i.e.:

```
df_wanted<-data.frame(origin=c("Norway","Sweden"),                 destination=c("dest_key_for_germany","dest_key_for_spain"))
df_wanted
```

Update: Since I actually have anonymous data, the data actually looks like this:

```
# using anonymized data:
df$destination[df$destination=="Germany"]<-"###123A"
df$destination[df$destination=="Gerrmany"]<-"#KL237#"
df_names$destination_typed[df_names$destination_typed=="Germany"]<-"###123A"
df_names$destination_typed[df_names$destination_typed=="Gerrmany"]<-"#KL237#"
df_names$destination_alternatives[df_names$destination_alternatives=="Germany"]<-"###123A"
df_names$destination_alternatives[df_names$destination_alternatives=="Gerrmany"]<-"#KL237#"
df$destination[df$destination=="Spain"]<-"##957KA"
df$destination[df$destination=="Spaiin"]<-"KLU##ab"
df_names$destination_typed[df_names$destination_typed=="Spain"]<-"##957KA"
df_names$destination_typed[df_names$destination_typed=="Spaiin"]<-"KLU##ab"
df_names$destination_alternatives[df_names$destination_alternatives=="Spain"]<-"##957KA"
df_names$destination_alternatives[df_names$destination_alternatives=="Spaiin"]<-"KLU##ab"

df
df_names
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is just too simple. Actually, it was likely so simple and so badly explained by me (my first post at SO) that it was hard to understand what I wanted, so sorry for that! I only sorted the data first and then took the first similar (anonymized) country name that had a similarity score above a certain level. Using the anonymized data above:

```
df_names<-df_names %>% 
  arrange(destination_typed,destination_alternatives) %>% 
  filter(similarity_score>0.5) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(destination_typed))

df %>% 
  left_join(df_names,by=c("destination"="destination_typed")) %>% 
  mutate(destination=destination_alternatives) %>% 
  select(-destination_alternatives,-similarity_score) %>% 
  distinct()

# which is essentially the same as I wanted:

df_wanted
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using Levenshtein distance for two strings. Everything would be much easier if you have a vector of possible destinations to check against. Otherwise you'll need to compute pairwise similarity between all typed destinations, and this will get hairy.

```
library(RecordLinkage)
library(tidyverse)

destination_typed<-c("Germany","Gerrmany","Spain","Spaiin")
destination_groups<-c("Germany","Spain")

tibble(destination_typed) %>%
  mutate(group = map_chr(destination_typed,
                     ~ Vectorize(RecordLinkage::levenshteinDist, vectorize.args = "str2")(.x, destination_groups) %>%
                       (function(X)destination_groups[which(X == min(X))]))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, Brian! I am given only anonymized keys for each spelling and the similarity score between the different spellings, so I guess that part is done (I would love to do it myself, but I don't get to see what has been typed). So I have to only use the score I am given.

Comment: In that case, can you give an example of what they data would look like once you're given the scores? As it stands now we don't have any insight into what they data you receive looks like.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for not being clearer, Brian. I updated the code above, so that data is now anonymized which is the case in my case.

Comment: Ah man. I also misread a bit. This is a tough question because you don't really know how many groups you should have at the end of the day. If you produce a list of all possible destinations (with correct spelling) and anonymise that at the same time as the free-text, cross your fingers that you have at least one person spelling correctly per destination entered, you could: sort of figure out your number of groups `K`, compute a distance matrix, calculate a clustering with `K` groups, assign from that. without an apriori idea of `K` you'd have to infer it! Hard(er) and uncertain

Comment: Ok. Thanks!:) Note that I still have the similarity score to work from, only the names are anonymized. But I guess it is a bit harder than I thought it would be.